# The infamous triangle loop... with a twist

Tags: java

So I have to output a right angle triangle of asterisks... with a border. The triangle I can do no problem, but the border is causing me difficulties. I'm thinking another if/else inside the loop but I don't know how to phrase it. The result I want is this:

```
*******
* *****
*  ****
*   ***
*    **
*     *
*******
```

What I can get without help is this:

```
*******
  *****
   ****
    ***
     **
      *
```

And here is my code:

```
public class Pattern
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int WIDTH = 7;

        for (int row = 1; row <= (WIDTH); row++)
        {
            for (int col = 1; col <= (WIDTH); col++)
            {
                if (row <= col)
                {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }

                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } 

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("\n\nGoodbye!");
    }
 }
```

Comment: You are very close. Now think about the symmetric properties of your triangle. You know how how long and wide it is, and you need to **mirror** the border....

Comment: you want to print an `*` on each row's start and alternatively you do not want to print in this fashion 0, 1, 2,....5...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out :)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int WIDTH = 7;

    for (int row = 1; row <= (WIDTH); row++)
    {

        for (int col = 1; col <= (WIDTH); col++)
        {
            if (col ==1){
                System.out.print("*");
            }else if (row ==WIDTH){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            else if (row < col)
            {
                System.out.print("*");
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("\n\nGoodbye!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint, the border always on the first index and last index

Keep it on :D

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
public class Pattern
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final int WIDTH = 7;

        for (int row = 1; row < (WIDTH); row++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");

            for (int col = 1; col < (WIDTH); col++)
            {
                if (row <= col)
                {
                    System.out.print("*");
                }

                else
                {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                } 

            }

            System.out.println("");
        }

        for(int i = 1; i <= (WIDTH); i++) {

            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nGoodbye!");
    }
 }
```